How to disable revoka when Logout event is trigged in ABP Framework?
Does everyone know the way to disable revoka api in ABP when logout event is fired, because i had a system to generate manually tokens for using and it's not saved into database as manual OpenIddict Server Auth, so now when i click on logout button, there is no anything to happen because it will call api to revoke token first but the token was not saved before in DB so it throws exception then we stuck on that ?
